# Creating a Grade Calculator in Visual Studio's 2019 (VB) and struggling with the code a bit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2019 to help accumulate test score data.

I have a Label named `Score`, and Textboxes for `Score Total`, `Score Count`, and `Score Average` that are all read only. I also button to `Add` and `Clear` scores, as well as `Exit`.

I have the code done for the Clear Scores and Exit buttons, but I am struggling with the Add button and getting all the scores input and summed.

My goal is to display the sum of all the scores in the `Score Total` box,  the number of scores in the `Score Count` box, and their average in the `Score Average` box.

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Class GradeCalculator
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim ScoreTotal As Decimal
    Dim ScoreCount As Decimal
    Dim Average As Integer

    Private Sub frmClearScores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmClearScores.Click
        score = 0
        ScoreTotal = 0
        ScoreCount = 0
        Average = 0

        txtscore.Text = ""
        txtscoretotal.Text = ""
        txtscorecount.Text = ""
        txtaverage.Text = ""

        txtscore.Select()
    End Sub

    ' This is the "Add" button
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I finish this?

Comment: Button2_Click is the Add button should note

Comment: I would use [Decimal.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__) to make sure you have a valid score in the TextBox. Then do additional checks, like making sure the value is >= 0.

Comment: @Gman23456 If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please provide more details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class GradeCalculator
    Dim ScoreTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim ScoreCount As Integer = 0

    Private Sub frmClearScores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmClearScores.Click
        ScoreTotal = 0
        ScoreCount = 0

        txtscore.Text = ""
        txtscoretotal.Text = ""
        txtscorecount.Text = ""
        txtaverage.Text = ""

        txtscore.Select()
    End Sub

    ' This is the "Add" button
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ScoreTotal += CInt(txtscore.Text)
        ScoreCount += 1

        txtscore.Text = ""
        txtscoretotal.Text = ScoreTotal.ToString()
        txtscorecount.Text = ScoreCount.ToString()
        txtaverage.Text = (CDec(ScoreTotal)/ScoreCount).ToString()

        txtscore.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton Typo. But now I look again, there were some inconsistencies in the original question based on when the OP chose Integer vs Decimal (If the `score` member variable was `Integer`, then `ScoreTotal` could be, too, at least in the context of grades. Also, the `score` variable was never used. So I've updated the answer now to reflect all of that.